# Unable to register default service worker. Service worker script threw an exception during script evaluation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm making an application using laravel as the backend and reactjs as the frontend using inertia, I'm trying to configure push notifications/browser notification in it using FCM.

Initially, they worked fine but when I got back to working on the project after some time, they didn't work.

This is my firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
 authDomain: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
 projectId: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
 storageBucket: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
 messagingSenderId: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
 appId: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
 measurementId: process.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(payload => {
 console.log("Received background message ", payload);
 console.log(
      "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
      payload
 );
 const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
 const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: payload.notification.image
 };

 self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

this is App.jsx

```
async function registerServiceWorker() {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register("../../public/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
            .then(function(registration) {
                console.log("Service Worker Registered!");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Service Worker Registration Failed: ", error);
            });
    }
}

// Call this function whenever you need to re-register the service worker
registerServiceWorker();
```

this is how I'm trying to get the device token:

```
  const getDevToken = async () => {
        Notification.requestPermission().then(async permission => {
            console.log(permission);
            if (permission === "granted") {
                const token = await getToken(messaging, {
                    vapidKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_VAPID_KEY
                });
                console.log(token);
                setData({
                    ...data,
                    deviceToken: token
                });
                setdevToken(token);
            }
        });
    };
```

Also the messaging instance I have used to get the device token is(I don't remember why I made this file) defined in another file named push-notification.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
export const onMessageListener = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      resolve(payload);
    });
  });
```

I always get this error while trying to register the service worker

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. ServiceWorker script at http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-messaging-sw.js for scope http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope threw an exception during script evaluation. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

I also get this:

> Service Worker Registration Failed:  DOMException: The operation is insecure.

I did trying checking if I had my service worker path wrong but that wasn't the case.